# How to Update My Project Settings to Support iOS 5.1.1 or Later?

Tags: ios, xcode, project-settings

This has to be one of the simplest fixes. There must be something I'm just not seeing/getting.

I am in the process of converting my app to `64-bit` so that I can deploy it to the app store. I got the warnings in my project and updated them like Xcode asks. However, I don't know how to update my project settings to support iOS 5.1.1. I just can't find that area.

I presume this is the reason why I cannot set my Architectures to “Standard Architectures (including `64-bit`).” Instead, I only have the option of "Standard architectures `(armv7, arm64)` - `$(ARCH_STANDARD)`"

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you really need to support iOS 5.1.1? There's little reason to support anything before iOS 7 with iOS 9 coming out soon.

Comment: Well I can't submit my app without completing this process. And it doesn't have to be exact 5.1.1 it can be further

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your Project in the Project Navigator,
2. Select the **Info** tab, and then
3. Set the **iOS Deployment Target** to the version of iOS you want to target (in your case 5.1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that you can't simultaneously support 64-bit and pre-ios6...